# Java rest (javax.ws.rs) POST not always working

Tags: java, android, rest, jax-rs, retrofit2

I'm creating a service which is a simple CRUD for now. I have a post method that I want to call from an Android application. It worked before, but suddenly I only can call it when I'm using Postman or something. From mobile it's not working.

I see it going through the filter with debugger, but it never gets into the method. When I remove the filter I get the same result, so I know the filter isn't the problem.. Anybody has any idea why this could happen?

Some code snippets below:

The endpoint

```
@POST
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/contact")
public void opslaanContactbericht(ContactRequest request) {
    contactService.opslaanBericht(request);
}
```

The android api interface (Retrofit2. Header removed, but i know that part works in filter)

```
@POST("contact")
@Headers("validheader")
Call<Contact> opslaanContact(@Body Contact contact);
```

Snippet where I call the interface:

```
BackendApi api = retrofit.create(BackendApi.class);
Contact contact = new Contact();
contact.setName(this.naamTextview.getText().toString());
contact.setEmail(this.emailTextview.getText().toString());
contact.setBericht(this.berichtTextview.getText().toString());

Call<Contact> call = api.opslaanContact(contact);
call.enqueue(this);
```

If there is more info needed just ask me.. Never seen anything like this before, so I really don't know what info is most usefull..

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the correct headers in your Retrofit, which are not set by default:

```
 @Headers({"Content-type: application/json"})
```

Comment: Seeing your comment i though.. Damn if that's it i really missed that.. The problem was that a property had a wrong name in the request..

Comment: without this header it also works.. Thanks for you answer though

Answer (score 0):

A property in the request had a incorrect name.. Weard enough it gives a positive response on the side of Android, but it never reaches the code nor gives an error.. Brilliant wtf, but its solved now